# NSBundle may not respond to +loadNibNamed:owner:options:

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, nib

I am receiving the above warning in my code. I looked up the method in the documentation and found it was declared in `UINibLoading.h`. I tried importing this, but the warning didn't disappear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`loadNibNamed:owner:options:` is an instance method, as indicated by the leading `-` in the header file and in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html).

```
- (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

If this were

```
+ (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

that would have been a class method.

You need to first get the main bundle (i.e. the app bundle of the app you're developing) by the class method `+mainBundle`, and then apply `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`, as in

```
 [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"foo" owner:self options:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks. So I didn't need to import that file at all

Comment: Casebash: Were you coming from Cocoa? AppKit's `+[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:]` *is* a class method, unlike its UIKit counterpart.

Comment: I mainly do Cocoa (not Touch), and I didn't know `+[NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:]` existed :p